# CPLEX keeps restarting in Pyomo

Tags: python, cplex, solver, pyomo, cplex-python-api

I tried running my model by adding the following settings to CPLEX.

```
##Model Code
.
.
.
.
import cplex

opt = SolverFactory('cplex') 

opt.options["threads"] = 8
opt.options['timelimit'] = 100
opt.options["mip cuts disjunctive"]=3

results = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
```

After the stipulated time limit of 100s, CPLEX keeps restarting itself to solve the problem. I had to close my IDE to stop the solving process.

Before adding in the options, all was normal, as in CPLEX stops after solving without restarting.

May I ask if anyone could advise and why this is happening and is there anything I need to do to prevent this?

My model is just a typical disjunctive problem with no re-solving processes invoked.

Thank you!